# Passing Variables through Functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make it where if one function runs and defines the variable the other function will be able to reconize the function. I'm a little new to Javascript so my code may be just a bunch of jibberish.

```
function next() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)
    document.getElementById("image").src = picture[random];
    console.log(random);
}

function who() {
    var thing = things[random];
    var text = document.getElementById("am").innerHTML = "I am " + thing + ".";
    console.log(text);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var random;

function next() {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
    document.getElementById("image").src = picture[random];
    console.log(random);
}

function who() {
    var thing = things[random];
    var text = document.getElementById("am").innerHTML = "I am " + thing + ".";
    console.log(text);
}
```

Comment: Yes. I think this is better than mine because everytime next() is used, random will change.

Comment: I tried that but for some reason it says "I am undefined." I had defined the variable things defined earlier. For all my code go [link](http://www.codecademy.com/jeremy.vidaurri/codebits/Bs1VsA)

Answer (score 0):

Define the random variable first, and then send it to the functions, like this;

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);

next(random);
who(random);

function next(random) {

    document.getElementById("image").src = picture[random];
    console.log(random);
}

function who(random) {
    var thing = things[random];
    var text = document.getElementById("am").innerHTML = "I am " + thing + ".";
    console.log(text);
}
```

Comment: But then random won't change I need it to change every time I run next()